# Why the VARCHAR variable not working to use inside queries as column names in mysql stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there a solution for using variable filter in the select statement for a column name without concatenating it with the query ?.
**Not working**

```
BEGIN 
    Declare StartRow int;
    set StartRow = ((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize);



  SELECT 
t.qid,
t.title,
t.vote,
t.answer_count,
t.creation_date,
t.uid,
t.username,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.tag END) AS tag1,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.tid END) AS tid1,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 2 THEN t.tag END) AS tag2,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 2 THEN t.tid END) AS tid2,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 3 THEN t.tag END) AS tag3,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 3 THEN t.tid END) AS tid3,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 4 THEN t.tag END) AS tag4,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 4 THEN t.tid END) AS tid4,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 5 THEN t.tag END) AS tag5,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 5 THEN t.tid END) AS tid5
FROM
(
    SELECT
        questions.id as qid,
        title,
        creation_date,
        vote,
        answer_count,
        tags.id as tid,
        tag,            
        username,
        users.id as uid,            
        IF (@prev = qid ,@c := @c + 1,@c := 1) constantTagNumber,
        @prev := qid
    FROM    (   SELECT @prev := 0 ,@c := 1) var,question_tags
    INNER JOIN tags ON question_tags.tid = tags.id
    RIGHT JOIN questions ON question_tags.qid = questions.id 
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id=owner_id
    ORDER BY    qid,tid
) t
GROUP BY t.qid ORDER BY filter desc LIMIT StartRow,PageSize;         
END
```

> The problem is only with the last `order by filter`
>   here `filter` is a `varchar` variable that I am using as a parameter.

Since filter is a variable ,the above code is not working. 

Can anyone suggest an simple solution to make it work.

> Make It work means ,I need to use the column name to use as order by from parameter.

#### Update

```
   BEGIN 
    Declare StartRow int;
    set StartRow = ((PageNumber - 1) * PageSize);

set @sql1=(
  SELECT 
t.qid,
t.title,
t.vote,
t.answer_count,
t.creation_date,
t.uid,
t.username,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.tag END) AS tag1,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.tid END) AS tid1,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 2 THEN t.tag END) AS tag2,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 2 THEN t.tid END) AS tid2,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 3 THEN t.tag END) AS tag3,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 3 THEN t.tid END) AS tid3,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 4 THEN t.tag END) AS tag4,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 4 THEN t.tid END) AS tid4,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 5 THEN t.tag END) AS tag5,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 5 THEN t.tid END) AS tid5
FROM
(
    SELECT
        questions.id as qid,
        title,
        creation_date,
        vote,
        answer_count,
        tags.id as tid,
        tag,            
        username,
        users.id as uid,            
        IF (@prev = qid ,@c := @c + 1,@c := 1) constantTagNumber,
        @prev := qid
    FROM    (   SELECT @prev := 0 ,@c := 1) var,question_tags
    INNER JOIN tags ON question_tags.tid = tags.id
    RIGHT JOIN questions ON question_tags.qid = questions.id 
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id=owner_id
    ORDER BY    qid,tid
) t
GROUP BY t.qid); 
set @sql=CONCAT(@sql1," ORDER BY ",filter," desc LIMIT", StartRow,",",PageSize);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I Updated the above code ,what am I missing here .

Comment: No, you will have to concatenate any structural part of query for the database to be able to use it.

Comment: Thats very unfortunate, in place of simple select query above ,I have a complex one with a lots of variables inside.

Comment: It is possible to concatenate a query using standard if-else logic and executed as a prepared statement (google mysql stored procedure and prepared statement). I use that on a regular basis to handle more complex cases, and it works nicely

Comment: `set @sql1=(` should be a string. Now it is a different kind of variable: Everything up to the PREPARE has to be done with string manipulation (so the DBMS does not know that it is parse-able SQL until the PREPARE tells it so).

Comment: Place quotes in the `SET @sql1=`: `SET @sql1="SELECT ..all your sql";`

Comment: Thanks alot ,the problems solved ,I tried this earlier .It didn't worked .Finally I figured it out , the problem was on `@sql`  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting close: Change your code to create a VARCHAR with your SQL in it, use IF/ELSE logic to concatenate your order by in there. Then pass this SQL to the prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = "Your SQL";
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: It is what you want, but you just don't know it yet: The "SELECT @sql;" has to be processed with the four lines in my answer.

Comment: yep bro , I checked that ,nothing happens , 0 rows affected.

Comment: The main problem is in setting `@sql1` , I think its not the right way to do that .